# Two dimensional arrays, assigning just one dimension

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In Javascript we can do the following to create a two dimensional array and then assign a value in the first position of the first array.

```
var some_array = [[]]
x[0] = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I have seen this can't be done in VB.NET natively (or perhaps i just couldn't find how to).

```
Dim some_array As String(,)
some_array(0) = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

Then i got an error that tells i'm not specifying the two dimensions of the array.

Is there a way to achieve this in VB NET?

Comment: [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript does not have a multidimensional array. Instead, it has an array of arrays, aka jagged array. In vb.net, a 2d array of strings is defined like this: `dim mystring(,) as string`, while a jagged array of strings is defined like this: `dim mystring()() as string`. Using a jagged array, the first "row" is an array that each of it cells contains an array, so it's possible to initialize just one "column".

One more thing about the difference between multidimensional and jagged arrays, is that a jagged array can have different lengths of "columns", since each column is a 1d array. It is not the case with a multidimentional array, it has to have the same lenght for all its columns.
This also proves my point about javascript, since the following code line is valid:

```
var a =[[1,2],[4,5,6],[1]];
```

Comment: vb.net has this too, [link for reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfky451c(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

How about using Generic.List rather than an array?

```
Dim some_array As New List(Of List(Of String))
some_array.Add({"a", "b", "c"}.ToList())
```

Otherwise you'll need to provide at least one dimension...

```
Dim some_array(3)() As String
some_array(0) = {"a", "b", "c"}
```